# Using an enum in a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, enums

I'm declaring an enum as followed:

```
class HDD{
    enum hardwareInterface{ATA,SATA,SCSI,SAS};
    // ...
}
```

As you can see I want to create a virtual HDD.

Now, I want to create my constructor like that:

```
HDD(int platterQuantity,hardwareInterface interface, int IOPS,Platter platter){
    setPlatterQuantity(platterQuantity);
    setIOPS(IOPS);
    platter.setSectorQuantity(platter.sectorQuantity);
}
```

This constructor is finished yet, but there are missing some parts that I can't include my enum properly because I don't know how.

Can someone explain me please how to do it? 
And please a simple answer, otherwise I'm not allowed to use it. We only had 4 Coding lectures till now.

Comment: Change your argument `hardwareInterface interface` to e.g. `hardwareInterface hardwareInterface` - you used `interface` as an argument name which is not correct because `interface` is a reserved keyword in java

Comment: The trick s to read, and post, the error message from the compiler, instead of trying to guess, and force us to guess, what is wrong.

Comment: I can add the compiler messages 
http://imgur.com/DI3fQGg
but Szymon Stepniak already solved it

Comment: If the problem is solved please add an answer describing how you solved it and accept that answer

Comment: That was meant as an advice for you, as a programmer, and for all your future questions. Don't ignore error messages. Don't ask a question about an error without posting the error. And post them as text, in your question, rather than as images, on imgur.

Comment: I always read the compiler messages but this time I wasn't able to solve it because I didn't know that interface is reserved by Java and the compiler (atleast I didn't understand him saying that to me) didn't say me something so I could know that it wsa reserved

Comment: Good then. But remember that we might understand it better than you do, and that's why you ask a question in the first place.

Comment: This does not make sense: `platter.setSectorQuantity(platter.sectorQuantity);` without seeing the detail code I can guess that this line will effect exactly no change in state. Probably that needed to be simply `setSectorQuantity(platter.sectorQuantity)` or maybe better `setSectorQuantity(platter.getSectorQuantity())`.

Comment: Actually this makes no sense at all ... why would you supply `platter` as a parameter, when you only extract the `sectorQuantity`, why not create a copy and store the entire copy, or simply (but not advisable) store a reference. BTW ... try to maintain naming conventions ... an enum type is supposed to start with an uppercase. Variable names starting lowercase, etc ... My help will stop here ... until I see gradual progress in improving this.

Answer (score -2):

From [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087870/solvedjava-using-an-enum-in-a-constructor#comment42683577_27087870):

You used `interface` as an argument name, which is not correct because `interface` is a reserved keyword in java.

Change your argument `hardwareInterface interface` to e.g. `hardwareInterface hardwareInterface`.